# Not able to add attribute in directive in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this code in my directive

```
   compile: function compile (tElement, tAttributes, transcludeFn) {

        if (tAttributes.drag == 'false') {
            tElement.find('.myclass').removeAttr('draggable');
        }

        //attrs.$set('ngModel', 'new value');
        return {
            pre: function preLink (scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn) {
                // Pre-link code goes here
            },
            post: function postLink (scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn) {
```

This works fine

But i want to add attribute instead of remove attribute based on boolean like this

```
        if (tAttributes.drag == 'true') {
            tElement.find('.myclass').attr('draggable');
        }
```

But this is not working.

I thing i need to recompile element after adding but i don't know how to do it

Comment: If dragable is directive then look at  my answer how to add directive from within directive... http://stackoverflow.com/a/28622263/1505865

Comment: `$(tElement).find('.myclass').attr('draggable');` ????

Comment: @JenishRabadiya i tried someting like that before but i was not sure where to put in pre link or post link . also i get error $compile is not a function

Comment: include  `$compile` to the directive function like I have done. No need to prelink and postlink but don't try to compile element itself instead get children and compile it and then replace that children. I am considering you are having element directive.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I did include that $compile function and i used that i used inside postLink function and i get same error again

Comment: @JenishRabadiya can you please tell me how to use it in postLink or prelink case  like i have

Comment: I don't have much Idea about prelink and postlink but I would try it later. and if it gets success will create demo for you later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the attribute in template function of the directive definition.

```
module.run(function ($templateCache, $http) {
    $http.get('__templateURL__')
      .then(function (response){
        $templateCache.put('__templateID', response.data)
      })
  });

module.directive('x', function ($templateCache) {
    return {
      template: function (tEl, tAttrs) {
        var template = $($templateCache.get('__templateID')); 
        if (tAttrs.drag == 'true') {
          template.find('.myclass').attr('draggable');
        }
        return template[0].outerHTML;
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: can i pull template from file and then chnage its attribute. i can't write the whole html as string

Comment: Try this... 
`module.run(function ($templateCache, $http) {
    $http.get('__tempalteURL__')
        .then(function (response) {
            $templateCache.put('__templateID__', response.data);
        })
})
.directive('x', function ($templateCache) {
    return {
        template: function () {
            var el = $templateCache.get('__templateID__');
            //add the attribute
        }
    }
})`

Comment: can you write that in above answer , its very hard to understand that in comment

Comment: thanks for that , that will work if my template is simple html. my problem is template itself conatin another driective , so at ttime template is not yet compiled into full html so that i can add some attribute. any idea to fix that

Comment: That should not be a problem. If you still face the problem.. please create a plunker/fiddle for the same.

Answer (score 0):

jQlite (angular's "jQuery" port) doesn't support lookup by classes.

> [find()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) - Limited to lookups by tag name

So you should try [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
if (tAttributes.drag == 'true') {
    tElement[0].querySelector('.myclass').attr('draggable');
}
```

Comment: But that removing of attribute is working fine with the code i provided. its only that adding attribute is not wokring because i think the dircetive is already compiled when i add the directive so it dont take into effect

Comment: are you wrapped jquery over angular ?

Comment: what u mean by wrapping jquery

Comment: are you included jquery before angular.js ?

Comment: That's why you can use find method here.

Comment: ok , so now the original question , how to add attribute and then recompile it