# AngularJS : Expose ng-repeat scope to ng-transclude

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having a template with the following structure (address-contact-info.html):

```
<dd ng-repeat="contact in contactInfo | limitTo: displayedItems | orderBy:'desc'">
    <span ng-transclude></span>
</dd>
```

And a directive:

```
{
    templateUrl: 'address-contact-info.html',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        contactInfo: '='
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
        scope.displayedItems = 1;
    }
};
```

I want to use the directive like this:

```
<div address-contact-info contact-info="tel">
    <span>{{contact.number}}</span>
</div>
```

This means I want to access the ng-repeat scope inside my transcluded elements, but I don't know how to do that.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this, or is there a better way to do that?

Thanks for your help!

**Update**
Here a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4DYEUhHAPuJOLyG9omCT

**Update**

I found a solution that works for me, though I still have one problem.
The elements I want to transclude in the template have their own directives which require a parent directive.

Now when I call the transcludeFn inside my linkFn, I get the following error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'editableGroup', required by directive 'editable', can't be found!
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zriVyS7MzheSI8jcYM5d

In this plunker I haven't included the other directives, but I get a transcludeFb related error as well.

```
Cannot set property 'nodeValue' of undefined
```

Comment: Do you have a plunker for this?

Comment: Any reason you want the repeat in the directive template rather than the view?

Comment: Yes, because there will be more than just the repeat in the the template.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div address-contact-info contact-info="tel">
    <span>{{contact.number}}</span>
</div>
```

This snippet will be compiled with the scope of the controller which doesn't have a reference to contact. 
Hence the ng-repeat is not able to display any data.

Even the transcluded content will be compiled with the controller's scope. Not with the scope of the directive.

A hack for this is:
http://plnkr.co/edit/clrchL1HLtFQLZ4fctZx?p=preview

This may not be the correct/proper solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use this approach when getting the template asynchronously, right?

Comment: You can, Try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666974/not-able-to-add-attribute-in-directive-in-angular/28667449#28667449